# Creating model with two iterators that uses clip tool as input feature and clip feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, clip, iterator

[image]I have a Geodatabase containing each county as its own feature (~60 features). I have another Geodatabase containing data in the form of points, lines, and polygons for the entire state.  What I need to do is clip all the data to each county. I created an Iterator for the data and then just had a single county as the input for the clip tool. This created the clipped files I want, however, I have to repeat this process for every county. Is there way to have the data iterate and the counties iterate into the clip tool so that the output will be the clipped data for every county?

Comment: Have a look at the help file and search for sub-models, you need to embed a model within a model that is the only way you can achieve a loop within a loop using modelbuilder.

Comment: Once I embed a model how can I get the output of the clip tool to be unique? Such that the the output name is "county name is listed then the data clipped." This is where im confused because when you embed the iterator model the teal box that contains the values disappears.

Comment: I added a picture of the model I have right now. Everything fails when it gets to the output.

Comment: You need to have a master model with one iterator feeding into a sub model. Your current configuration will not work as one sub model will run to completion then the other.

Comment: @Hornbydd I think your comment has just enough content to be copy/pasted into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Hornbydd:

> Have a look at the help file and search for sub-models, you need to
>   embed a model within a model that is the only way you can achieve a
>   loop within a loop using ModelBuilder.

and:

> You need to have a master model with one iterator feeding into a sub
>   model. Your current configuration will not work as one sub model will
>   run to completion then the other.